# Use lscape but I want to rotate in the other direction

Tags: lscape

I'm using the `lscape` package with

```
\begin{landscape}
blalbla
\end{landcape}
```

It does the work but instead of rotating the text  `90` degrees I would like to rotate it in the other direction (i.e. `-90` degrees). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the command that does the rotation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\LS@rot}{90}{-90}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endlandscape}{90}{-90}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```